# How to identify some random widnows thrown while XCUITest running in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, ui-automation, xcuitest

We have UI automation code to test our app. While test suites are running randomly keychain throws a window to enter credentials to access keychain item. We are not sure when that window is thrown. Once Keychain throws a window to enter credentials our test case blocks.

How to identify that randomly thrown Window or UI, to enter credentials for keychain item.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that with `addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: _) { (alert) -> Bool in }` Where `alert` will be the system alert. Anytime a system alert is displayed this function is called. You simply set it in your `setUp` test function